# Why has Composer installed a version of a package that seems to conflict with the requirements?

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php

This looks like a simple issue, but I can't explain what's happening.

In `composer.json` for my Symfony project the twig version is specified as <2.0, to avoid breaking changes between v1 and v2.  However, Composer installs the latest Twig version (2.4.3) anyway.

```
php c:\php\composer\composer.phar depends -t "twig/twig"
twig/twig v2.4.3 Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
|--symfony/framework-standard-edition dev-develop (requires twig/twig <2.0)
|--symfony/symfony v2.8.24 (requires twig/twig ~1.34|~2.4)
|  `--symfony/framework-standard-edition dev-develop (requires symfony/symfony 2.8.*)
`--twig/extensions v1.5.1 (requires twig/twig ~1.27|~2.0)
   `--symfony/framework-standard-edition dev-develop (requires twig/extensions ^1.3)
```

Relevant chunk of composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/twig": "<2.0",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    etc
}
```

It looks to me like the requirements of the `symfony/symfony` and `twig/extensions` packages, combined with those of the project, would result in the highest possible 1.x version of Twig, 1.34.4, but that's not what happens.  Why?

EDIT:

Composer 1.4.2

Full `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/twig": "<2.0",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "^1.0",
        "royopa/fpdf-symfony2": "^1.0",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.0",
        "patchwork/jsqueeze": "^2.0",
        "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~2.0.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.1",
        "deployer/deployer": "^3.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Deleting composer.lock and completely updating and reinstalling gives me what I thought I should get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of composer are you using?

I tested that json file on a Linux Mint 17, with php 5.5 and composer 1.3.2 and the twig version installed is the right one (twig/twig - v1.34.4).

Can you try to paste your complete composer.json file?

Also, I suggest removing the composer.lock file and all the contents of the vendor folder and try the install again.

Comment: Thanks for looking, just updated with more info.  Will try a complete package reinstall

Comment: I had to remove this package: "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~2.0.0" because it requires php 7 and didn't work on my machine. 

But except that, the installation worked fine and the twig package installed is still the correct one:  1.34.4 (2017-07-04)

Comment: Thanks again - I've done the complete refresh, and now I'm getting 1.34.4 too!  So no idea why that would happen, and particularly why the "depends" command can give two different answers without any of the directly relevant info changing!  I'll chalk this up to a quirk, and move on.  Cheers!